# regex doesn't match multiple strings

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find multiple matches in my regex. Here is my regex

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{8}[#](FRI|SAT|SUN)[\r]$");
final Matcher m = p.matcher("09042012#SUN\r" + "09022012#FRI\r" + "09032012#SAT\r");
    while (m.find())
    {
        final String result = m.group();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

this works if the string has just one match, but if its consecutive matches it doesn't work. I have tried adding .+ at the end of my regex to make sure it atleast have one match. That doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` and `$` by default represent start/end of entire input (passed to Matcher), not start/end of lines.

If you want your regex to match only lines use in your regex [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) flag.
Also remove `[\r]` since characters after it are considered as placed in next line which means that `$` placed after `[\r]` can only match end of next line - in other words you would find only match which have next line empty.

So your code should look more like

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{8}[#](FRI|SAT|SUN)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
//                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
final Matcher m = p.matcher(
          "09042012#SUN\r" 
        + "09022012#FRI\r" 
        + "09032012#SAT\r");
while (m.find())
{
    final String result = m.group();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the multiline flag:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{8}[#](FRI|SAT|SUN)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

This will allow the `$` and `^` to match on the carriage returns `\r` in your input.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line start `^` and line end `$`, your code would work:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{8}[#](FRI|SAT|SUN)[\r]");
final Matcher m = p.matcher("09042012#SUN\r" + "09022012#FRI\r" + "09032012#SAT\r");
    while (m.find())
    {
        final String result = m.group();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```